# WPF Context Menu Event Source Keyboard vs. Mouse

Tags: wpf

Can one detect if a context menu is triggered by a keyboard shortcut vs. the mouse in the `ContextMenuOpening` event? I've tried various combinations of `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Apps)`, `Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Keys.Apps)` and `MouseButtonStates` but nothing works reliably.

Comment: `ContextMenuOpening` handler does not provide any feedback on that, and since context menu is shown on the release of key/mouse button, checking keyboard/mouse state inside the handler won't be of any use. That being said I guess you're stuck with handling `PreviewKeyUp` and `PreviewMouseUp` (or `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp`) and setting some kind of flag.

Comment: In the end, I added a PreviewKeyUp handler as suggested. Bummer.